# Dynamic select value in ractive

Tags: forms, ractivejs

When using ractive this works fine:

```
<select value='{{sortColumn}}'>
  {{#each type}}
    <option>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

As long as `sortColumn` itself is a fixed string.
My question is, what if I want to create several selects, indexed by a upper level array, something like:

```
{{#each list}}
  <select value='{{sortColumn}}'>
    {{#type[.]}}
      <option>{{this}}</option>
    {{/}}
  </select>
{{/each}}
```

Where `type` is indexed by a `list` element. This works great in terms of rendering, I get the right options rendered. But the value of the select itself is replicated as `sortColumn`, and thus observing it will be triggered for each of the individual selects with the same function with nothing to distinguish them besides the values.

How to avoid this? Is it possible to attribute (and observe) different names to each select?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, making a fiddle to illustrate the question would be great

Comment: PLase, make a fiddle so we can understand better your problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible - you can create a separate `sortColumns` object and use two-way binding with expressions like `sortColumns[this]`.

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    list: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    type: {
      a: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      b: [ 4, 5, 6 ],
      c: [ 7, 8, 9 ]
    },
    sortColumns: {}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  {{#each list}}
    <select value='{{sortColumns[this]}}'>
      {{#each type[this]}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  {{/each}}
  
  <p><code>sortColumns: {{JSON.stringify(sortColumns)}}</code></p>
</script>

<main></main>
```

Alternatively, your `list` could be an array of objects that store their `sortColumn` locally:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    list: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    type: {
      a: { sortColumn: 1, values: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
      b: { sortColumn: 4, values: [ 4, 5, 6 ] },
      c: { sortColumn: 7, values: [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  {{#each list}}
    {{#with type[this]}}
      <select value='{{sortColumn}}'>
        {{#each values}}
          <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
  
  <p><code>type: {{JSON.stringify(type)}}</code></p>
</script>

<main></main>
```