# How to get selected value from dropdown in a table when there is more then 1?

Tags: javascript, html, ractivejs

If I have a bunch of table rows and with select tags in them how would I get the selected value?

If the variable "selected_ingr_action" is the same for every row then when I select an item they all change instead of just the one.

I know I'm missing something.

```
{{#Ingredients}}
                <tr>
                    <td class="ingr-bid-col"></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <p class="ingr-name">{{Name}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="">{{VendorName}}</a><br />
                                <b>pack:</b><span>{{Pack}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <b>unit price</b><br />
                                    <span>{{UnitPrice}}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <b>case price</b><br />
                                    <span>{{CasePrice}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" value="{{selected_ingr_action}}">
                                    <option value="-1" selected disabled>Action</option>
                                    <option value="0">Rename</option>
                                    <option value="1">Edit Unit Price</option>
                                    <option value="2">Archive</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps you might be asking a much simpler question about why the rows are sharing the value. If this is the case, the short answer is to use a restricted reference (notice the `.`):

```
<select class="form-control" value="{{.selected_ingr_action}}">
    <option value="-1" selected disabled>Action</option>
    <option value="0">Rename</option>
    <option value="1">Edit Unit Price</option>
    <option value="2">Archive</option>
</select>
```

This causes the `selected_ingr_action` to be bound to the list item, not the root of the ractive instance.

You can access the result on each item with a wilcard observer:

```
r.observe('list.*.selected_ingr_action', function(n, o, k, i){
    console.log('list index', i, 'changed from', o, 'to', n);
});
```

[Check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/d56y6r1g/1/).

The behavior of defaulting to root, rather than current context, is [under consideration](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1776) to be changed to resolve to the current context.

Comment: I tried to use .observe(".selected_ingr_action",function(newValue){...}) to get newValue but it doesn't fire. How do I get the new value?

Comment: added example of using an observer

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to have a separate map of selected values, and use two-way binding to update that map (rather than a single `selected_ingr_action` property, or a `selected_ingr_action` property belonging to each item in the list). You can see an example of this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949108/2742396) - the details are different but the principle is the same.

```
{{#Ingredients :i}} <!-- note the index reference -->

...

<select class="form-control" value="{{selected_ingr_actions[i]}}">
  <option value="-1" selected disabled>Action</option>
  <option value="0">Rename</option>
  <option value="1">Edit Unit Price</option>
  <option value="2">Archive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do I get the selected_ingr_actions value?

Comment: not sure I understand the question? You can get/set it like any other value

Answer (score 1):

There are to ways to solve this.

First, bind the value of the select into data.

I.e. turn this string:

```html
<select class="form-control" value="selected_ingr_action">
```

into this:

```html
<select class="form-control" value="{{selected_ingr_action}}">
```

Assuming that your data structure is something like this:

```js
var Ingredients = [
   {
       Name: String,
       VendorName: String,
       UnitPrice: Number,
       CasePrice: Number,
       selected_ingr_action: String
   },
   /* other entries */ 
];
```

As a second thought, maybe you don't want to store action type inside your data. 
I beleive that better approach would be to use so-called [Proxy Events](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/proxy-events) with custom arguments and [Method Calls](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/method-calls).

Here, I add key into your template and when you change your select value, corresponding event handler are called with the index of your row.

Like this:

```html
{{#each Ingredients: key}} <!-- <<< note that key -->
    <!-- skip -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <select class="form-control" on-change="changeAction(this, key)" value="{{this.selected_ingr_action}}">
                 <!-- note this too                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
                 <option value="-1" selected disabled>Action</option>
                 <option value="0">Rename</option>
                 <option value="1">Edit Unit Price</option>
                 <option value="2">Archive</option>
             </select>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Note, into your Ractive component you can introduce method `changeAction`, which will receive current row (with corresponding `Name`, `VendorName` etc. properties) and it's `key`. Like this:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    /* skip */
    changeAction: function (ingridient, key) {
        // do something with that ingridient
    }
    /* skip */
});
```

Comment: The key only returns the index of the row. How do I get what was selected in the dropdown? I tried using value but it only returns the last one that was selected not the current one.

Comment: Use value, but make sure that you've explicitely set the current context (i.e. context of the current row). I've updated answer.